# Are there any limitations in downloading multiple files from browser using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery plugin to download multiple files. I'm using bootstrap data table to display the data. This is working fine, but are there any limitations on number of files and size from the browser point of view or client side. I have to give the maximum limit values to the client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limitations on how many files to download, but if you are displaying say 3000+ records all at the same time, it will give you issues. The client side is the bottleneck and the best thing to prevent is pagination. It's not the number of files to download, it's the client having to render all those DOM elements that is going to eat up your performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. I got your point. It will solve my problem.

Comment: Might add, that the browsers tagged in your question, do have limitation in regard of how much memory can be allocated to one tab. A quick search shows numbers between 1.5-3.5 GB for a Chrome tab (depending on Chrome version and OS), while it's 1.4 GB for an IE tab. These numbers aren't official numbers, they're just what other users have tested.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that point, So total files size should be lesser than 3,5 GB right ?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,**

Modern browsers don't allow to download multiple files in default settings due to security reasons. Still, you can enable multiple file download by some client-side configurations. Please refer this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_81YiVoPZ7I) to enable multiple downloads in google chrome.

**The best solution for such scenarios is to compress and zip all files together with your back-end service and let it download the zip file.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try it.